# Will this question be put "on hold" as proofreading?

Tags: support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I am going to post this question here:

### What is the proper way to describe this sentence?

> **King ordered Mary to work in Court, but she doesn't like it because
> she thinks by this way king will meet her always & she also thinks
> king will seperate her & husband.**
>
> Mary thinks it makes easy to king to meet her & also thinks king will
> seperate her & husband. I find difficult to phrase this sentence with
> less words.

But I wonder if this question will be put **on-hold**?

Comment: What part of the quote is hard to understand?

Answer (score 4):

> King ordered Mary to work in Court, but she doesn't like it because she thinks by this way king will meet her always & she also thinks king will seperate her & husband.

It's a long sentence. I think it's confusing you.

If your question is "How to write the whole sentence in another way?", I think it will be put on hold as proofreading.

If you have difficulty understanding some part of the sentence, please specify that part, and we will help you.

I am not sure what you meant by "What is the proper way to describe this sentence?". Are you looking for its meaning? Are you asking us to check for errors? What is it?